# customized Tab structure for web parts

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation, design

I am currently looking to design a custom tab structure nav bar for my web parts.

this navigation bar should display different web parts on clicking different tabs within its structure.
Any leads on it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it via JQuery.

A [demo](http://info.summit7systems.com/blog/tabbed-web-parts-in-sharepoint-2013-office-365) about Tabbed web part for your reference.

Comment: Hmmmm...No luck?

Comment: it did the work but i kind of want something different.